# Determine if a point lies on one of two hemispheres

Tags: geometry

Let $n$ be a normal vector, which belongs to a plane $E$, which divides a sphere $S$, with center at origin and $r=1$. $E$ passes through the origin.

I am looking for the case distinction, in order to determine on which of the two resulting hemispheres an arbitrary unit vector $q$, starting from the origin, lies.

Thanks for the help and answers in advance!

Comment: Presumably we know $n$'s coordinates $(x,y,z)$. It is common to associate the upper hemisphere with $z>0$.

Comment: Hint:  Think about the dot product

Comment: Hello Kurt, thanks for the answer.
with hemisphere I mean in this case the two halves which originate after an intersection with the plane. However, the position of $E$ depends on $n$ and not, as you imply, simply the XY-plane. 

$q \in R^{3}$ and $n \in R^{3}$ with $\vert q \vert = \vert n \vert = 1$ are known.

Comment: Ok. And $n$ is normal *to* the plane ? Or does it lie *in* the plane ?

Comment: Something like ? What exactly ?

Comment: Assuming now the vector $n$ is normal to the plane $E$. This does not tell us to which side of $E$ it is pointing. $n$ and $-n$ define the same plane. Do you think that the answer about the hemisphere can be given ?

Comment: Hessian Normal Form/Point Normal Form: $x \cdot n = 0$

Comment: OK. Our comments crossed. What do you think ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments Kurt.
I agree with you that the assignment of normal vectors to the plane is surjective. However, I still think that there must be a unique solution, since I am able to solve this problem numerically quickly and easily. Unfortunately, my algebraic skills are limited. My first thought was to transform the $n$ vector onto the $z$-axis of the origin and to apply this transformation to $q$ and then to proceed as you presented at the beginning or to perform the case differentiation on the basis of the $z$-component of $q$. But to be honest, I think it must be easier.

Comment: I only realize now that $n$ and $q$ are given, and the question is if $q$ lies on the same side of $n$. Reiterating Ross Millikan's comment : What does the dot procuct $n\cdot q$ tell you about the angle between $n$ and $q$ ?

Comment: Haha. Is it really that simple? If $n \cdot q>0 $, $q$ lies on the same side of $E$ as $n$. Seems to be true...